# call a var dynamically with a regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
$foo = "yes";
$pattern = "{foo}";

$pattern = preg_replace('#{(\w+)}#', $'${1}', $pattern);
```

Can I call a var dynamically with a regex? something like the code above?
to replace the {foo} to $foo and return 'yes'?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), like this:

```
<?php

    $foo = "yes";
    $pattern = "{foo}";

    echo $pattern = preg_replace_callback('#{(\w+)}#',
                                    function($m) use($foo){
                                        return $$m[1];
                                    }, $pattern);

?>
```

Output:

```
yes
```